# After generating a model with random body parts. Cover the area between those parts to make the 3D model look good

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, runtime, shader

I have human models with three body parts: Head, torso, and legs. Rig and animations for these models I am getting from Mixamo. I am taking two human models(parents) and alternately getting body parts from parents to create a new child. I am transferring skinned meshes of body parts according to the child's rig(which has been taken from one of the parents). Because parents have a little bit different rigs(from Mixamo) those body parts not connecting correctly and there are little gaps between them. I am thinking about how to fill those gaps. Can somebody please help... because I'm stuck? It would be great...

Parents: [Image of parents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaEQf.png)

Child: [Image of the child after getting body parts from parents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvFLg.png)

**Note that this is not always the case. There are other combinations that the connection of the parts will proceed + - not bad**

Skinned mesh transfer code

```
public static void TransferSkinnedMeshes(SkinnedMeshRenderer[] skinnedMeshRenderersList, Transform newArmature, Transform newParent)
        {
            foreach (var t in skinnedMeshRenderersList)
            {
                string cachedRootBoneName = t.rootBone.name;
                var newBones = new Transform[t.bones.Length];
                for (var x = 0; x < t.bones.Length; x++)
                    foreach (var newBone in newArmature.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
                        if (newBone.name == t.bones[x].name)
                        {
                            newBones[x] = newBone;
                        }

                Transform matchingRootBone = GetRootBoneByName(newArmature, cachedRootBoneName);
                t.rootBone = matchingRootBone != null ? matchingRootBone : newArmature.transform;
                t.bones = newBones;
                Transform transform;
                (transform = t.transform).SetParent(newParent);
                transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            }
        
        }

        static Transform GetRootBoneByName(Transform parentTransform, string name)
        {
            return parentTransform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().FirstOrDefault(transformChild => transformChild.name == name);
        }
```

I've tried to write shader with the help of chatGPT... but it was not working. Also, I have wanted to get the same rig from Mixamo, but because I am setting key positions for auto-rigging by eye gauge I couldn't get good results

Comment: Search for "mesh hole filling" and you should find a bunch of papers. But I would expect that a reliable implementation will be fairly complicated, and it might not work at all for unconnected parts like you seem to have. I would expect it to be simpler to just fix the meshes to either hide the seam, or ensure it is common for all body parts.  Or at least have a human mark the edges that should be joined.

Comment: Is chatGPT giving badvice again? I don't quite understand the purpose of combining two parents (there might be an easier way to achieve what you want), but I agree with @JonasH. You would have to programmatically create new faces in between the vertex loops or indeed just manually change the mesh a bit to allow for some slack.

Answer (score 0):

Mesh hole filling is the way to go. Yet your case allows for some "easy" way to go as the two separated parts are roughly the same shape. Here's what i would do:

- first implement a 2D Delaunay triangulation (you can find free code on Git)
- compute the two contours to be connected (you'll need the halfedge date structure on your mesh to do so efficiently).
- project the two contours in 2D space (along the normal of either of the contour)
- just to be sure enlarge one by a small factor and shrink the other by a small factor.
- use Delaunay 2D on this 2 contours to connect them.
- re-project in 3D space.
  I've tested it myself, it pretty fast and robust for those kind of use cases.